# Default database is not showing in PgAdmin4 Nor there is any Server

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

[image]

I want to import a database in my pgAdmin 4  but as I installed it there is no default database in that plus there is also no server. First time I am installing this on my PC. Please help me out with the procedure of how to import the database.

Comment: Guess what? PostgreSQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: Just Add New Server and provide information that needed.